# Physical system for exchanging entanglement between types of particles

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-entanglement, quantum-computer

What is an example of physical system in which entanglement is transferred from one pair of particles to a different pair of a completely different type of particle?

For instance, if I have two photons with circular polarizations described by the Bell state $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|LL\rangle+ |RR\rangle)$ interacting with some pair of two-level systems initialized to $|01\rangle$, what conditions make it possible for this pair of systems to interact with the photons and take on an entangled state like  $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|01\rangle+ |10\rangle)$?

Must the two-level systems' states need to be defined in terms of angular momentum? How can I use conservation laws to predict allowed transitions (e.g. $|01\rangle \rightarrow \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|01\rangle+ |10\rangle)$ but $|00\rangle$ does not transition)?

I would especially appreciate any examples from quantum information experiments, like an interface between some photonics system and a superconducting qubit transferring photon entanglement -> qubit entanglement.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the interface: I found one example that would allow for conversion of energy between photons and phonons via an optomechanical crystal [1], which seems to be a waveguide-like device that sustains both mechanical and optical modes. In turn, the resulting phonons can be converted into microwave-frequency EM fields on chip using a piezoelectric device. In the case of [2], this conversion was accomplished using an "interdigitated transducer" to achieve frequencies compatible with superconducting qubits. Such coupling has already been demonstrated, for example in [3].

Now to speculate an answer: This process *should* preserve entanglement since it directly converts a photonic state into a superconducting qubit state. I plan on looking into this more however.

References

1. Eichenfield, Matt, et al. "Optomechanical crystals." Nature 462.7269 (2009): 78.
2. Vainsencher, Amit, et al. "Bi-directional conversion between microwave and optical frequencies in a piezoelectric optomechanical device." Applied Physics Letters 109.3 (2016): 033107.
3. Manenti, Riccardo, et al. "Circuit quantum acoustodynamics with surface acoustic waves." Nature communications 8.1 (2017): 975.